# Javascript dynamically creating HTML elements with addEventListener functions not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, createelement

As in this example, i like to create HTML elements and attach them onclick functions that is part of the object instance, any way to do this?
when clicking it getting :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getObj is not defined
```

```js
function DataSources() {

  var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
  newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
  newCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.ds_checkbox("test2");
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("multi_select").append(newCheckbox);
  this.addLabel = function() {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = "test";
    label.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.getObj("test");
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("multi_select").append(label);
  }
  this.getObj = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
  };
  this.ds_checkbox = function(p) {
    console.log(key);
  };
}
var datasources = new DataSources();
datasources.addLabel();
```

```html
<div id="multi_select">
</div>
```

Comment: There is no "getObj" function defined.  However there is "this.getObj".

Comment: no its the same error when adding this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options to solve your problem:

- Store `this` in a variable at constructor execution time for further use by the event callback
- Use an arrow function as the event callback, to retain `this` at declaration time
- Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force `this` value to the class instance

In the following code I used the first option with this line:

```
var self = this;
```

```js
function DataSources() {

  var self = this;
  var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
  newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
  newCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
    self.ds_checkbox("test2");
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("multi_select").append(newCheckbox);
  this.addLabel = function() {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = "test";
    label.addEventListener("click", function() {
      self.getObj("test");
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("multi_select").append(label);
  }
  this.getObj = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
  };
  this.ds_checkbox = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
  };
}
var datasources = new DataSources();
datasources.addLabel();
```

```html
<div id="multi_select">
</div>
```

You could also replace event callbacks with arrow functions like this:

```js
function DataSources() {

  var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
  newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
  newCheckbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.ds_checkbox("test2");
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("multi_select").append(newCheckbox);
  this.addLabel = function() {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = "test";
    label.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.getObj("test");
    }, false);
    document.getElementById("multi_select").append(label);
  }
  this.getObj = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
  };
  this.ds_checkbox = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
  };
}
var datasources = new DataSources();
datasources.addLabel();
```

```html
<div id="multi_select">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, can you explain why i need to save "this" as self?

Comment: Because in a regular (not arrow) function, `this` is being evaluated at execution time of the current function, not taking into account the surrounding context. On the other hand, a variable can be resolved in the surrounding context thanks to JavaScript's closures.